# jQuery : how to access the name of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pls see the following html code

```
<input id="product_code1" name="Samsung"><br>
<input id="product_code2" name="Apple"><br>
<input id="product_code3" name="Huawei"><br>
<input id="product_code4" name="Motorola"><br>
```

and the jquery code

```
$( "input[id*='product']" ).val( 'test' );
```

the result will display 4 textbox with the value of 'test' as default, but now i like to display 4 textbox with the value of the product name, means first textbox will display 'Samsung', 2nd textbox will display 'Apple' & so on, so what command should i put in the jquery code ? pls advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`.val(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function):

```js
$("input[id^='product_']").val(function() {
        return this.name;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="product_code1" name="Samsung"><br>
<input id="product_code2" name="Apple"><br>
<input id="product_code3" name="Huawei"><br>
<input id="product_code4" name="Motorola"><br>
```

For each input element it will invoke the function that will return the value to set.

#### Bonus

To make it even more concise you could consider a helper function, e.g.:

```
jQuery.prop = function(name) {
    return function() {
        return this[name];
    }
};
```

Then, the code becomes:

```
$("input[id^='product_']").val($.prop('name'));
```

Comment: Ah I thought there might be a shorter way.

Comment: Jack, your solution is birilliant. It's so concise!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("input[id*='product']").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.val($this.attr("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="product_code1" name="Samsung"><br>
<input id="product_code2" name="Apple"><br>
<input id="product_code3" name="Huawei"><br>
<input id="product_code4" name="Motorola"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[id*='product']").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.prop("name"));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/hefz5a84/)